# For finite collection of groups, $G_{1},G_{2},\dots, G_{n}$, $\exists G$ such that $G_{i}$ is a homomorphic image of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, direct-product

Let $G_{1},G_{2},\dots, G_{n}$ be any finite collection of finite groups.  **I need to prove that there exists a finite group $\mathbf{G}$ such that each $\mathbf{G_{i}}$ is a homomorphic image of $\mathbf{G}$.**

Since this problem is in the section we're doing on direct products, I let $G = G_{1} \times G_{2} \times \cdots \times G_{n}$. By a definition we were given of direct product, $G$ is a group with componentwise multiplication as the group operation; i.e., for $x_{i}, \, y_{i} \in G_{i}$, $(x_{1},x_{2}, \cdots, x_{n})\cdot (y_{1},y_{2},\cdots, y_{n}) = (x_{1}y_{1}, x_{2}y_{2},\cdots, x_{n}y_{n}) \in G$.

Now, I know that $\forall x_{i} \in G_{i}$, we have the projection epimorphism $\pi_{i}(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots, x_{i}, \cdots, x_{n}) = x_{i}$, and so we are able to map any element of $G$ to an element of one of the $G_{i}$, but how do we map the entire **group** $G$ to the entire **group** $G_{i}$?

Am I able to use this projection epimorphism, and if so, how do I "sup it up" so that it can take care of whole groups and not just elements of groups?

If not, how do I prove this?

Thank you.

Comment: $G_i$ being a homomorphic image of $G$ means there exists a surjective homomorphism $f:G\to G_i$. In this case your $\pi_i$ does the job.

Comment: @s.harp it can't be that easy, can it? How would I write that out nicely?

Comment: If $x_i\in G_i$ then $\pi_i(1,...,1,x_i,1,...,1)=x_i$. Thus the homomorphism $\pi_i :G_1\times...\times G_n\to G_i$ is surjective.

Comment: @s.harp you rock. Thank you.